# InstallShield use product version in Path variable

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield-2011

Is there a way to use the product version number as a variable when building an path for where the exe gets dumped or for other scenarios, etc.

That way I can set the variable once and just have it automatically be updated everywhere.
(eventually, I want to pass in the version number, but thats down the road.)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried lots of things but there seems to be no way to use a variable product version string (there's a number of threads on the net as well that come to this conclusion). Moreover in our project we also use the version string in the shortcut names, the setup file name etc and found no way to store this in a single place. We found a very manageable solution though via automation. Here's a sample that updates version number and filename using VBScript, but you can also use C# for instance.

```vb
Set ISWIProject = CreateObject("IswiAuto19.ISWiProject")
ISWIProject.OpenProject "Our.ism"
ISWIProject.ProductVersion = "4.0.2.0"
ISWIProject.ISWiProductConfigs.Item("Release").SetupFileName = "App_4.0.2.0_Setup"
```

Answer (score 1):

When building with `IsCmdBld.exe` you can specify the build location with the -b option.  The bummer of this is that it will actually change the ism.  It always annoys me that a build will change a source controlled file.

It's also trivial to pass in the product version on the commandline with -y  (oddly - this doesn't change the .ism file)

I don't think you can specify a property such as [ProductVersion] in the release location, nor was I able to create a path variable and use that as the release location.